# How to replace .live() with .on() when targeting the document rather than an element within

Tags: javascript, jquery

My understanding of the .on() function is that you call the function on the parent element of the target. The original jQuery I am changing is this:

```
 $(document).live('keydown',function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '80')) { //cntrl + p
        event.preventDefault();
        printOrder();
    }
 });
```

So it is called directly on the document. My understanding is that I should be calling it like this:

```
 $(PARENT OF DOCUMENT).on('keydown', document, function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '80')) { //cntrl + p
        event.preventDefault();
        printOrder();
    }
 });
```

I found plenty of answers on the .live() to .on() conversion, but they all referenced using a parent element. How can you reference the parent element of the document?

Comment: The `document` has no parent. You can however simply use `#on()` on it.

Comment: Change your `.live` to `.on` boom you are done. Go http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more examples and how to use it

Comment: .live is deprecated.. https://api.jquery.com/live/.. Use .on just like you use .live

Comment: Really? I got the impression from all of the posts that I read that I had to target an element within!

Comment: @bboysupaman please see documentation first before going through all kinds of answers. Depending on the situation, you might need/not need to delegate the event to a parent

Comment: Why did you have to use `live` at the first place? You should have simply used `bind`.

Comment: The `document` is always available, it can't be removed or inserted dynamically, which means the use of `live` is not neccessary to begin with.

Comment: @LShetty I am just helping out with some debugging. It's not really my thing (yet... I'm learning). But, I didn't write the code in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `.live` to `.on` in your example above.

`#document` has no parent.